# how to receive emails using the aws ses and aws sns?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I am trying to receive emails on a domain email like xyz@example.com and I have done the following steps to get the results but am unable to get that.

Firstly, I have created an SNS topic and linked that SNS topic with HTTPS protocol to a rest API to receive the incoming email details. And then in SES firstly I have verified the domain and then in the email receiving section I have created a rule set and activated that rule set and I have not added recipient condition and in the action I am using AWS SNS topic and same topic which I have created for this email receiving. But I am not able to receive the email content to the endpoint which I have linked to SNS topic. I have added the MX record in Cloudflare DNS and I am using us-east1 for value endpoint.

How can I implement this?

Comment: Did you confirm SNS subscription of you https endpoint? Also, what is the size of the email that you have received? Since you're using SNS, limit is 256KB

Comment: yes i have confirmed the https endpoint and currently I am sending normal text hello or hello world

Comment: Try to break it up to isolate the problem : First see if only SNS works and if you are able to send notification to the topic. Check SES separately. Then figure out what went wrong.

Comment: sns working because whenever i am changing in rule set I am getting this response {notificationType\":\"Received\" } json. but when i am sending email I am not receiving any payload

Comment: @DevangSanghani i am not able to understand what went wrong with ses. because I have also added mx record on cloudflare dns

Comment: Any nees on this? I am having the same problem.

Comment: yes i have implemented the whole process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your destination rules, if you need receive all traffic domain add your naked domain: example.com, if you need receive traffic for specific address: user@example.com, also check if You have more than one MX record, if You have two or more setup priority for SES.